# Use the Pyrebase to create the anonymous user and connect the Firebase and access databases

Tags: python, database, firebase, pyrebase

I have a many data(eg: battery status)  in the client pc (about 10 pc) want to monitor and i plan to write the application to do this and upload the monitor data to the Firebase (database of main account).

Then use the dashboard on the Firebase to watching data send from client pc in the other place.

Eg: Client1、2、3 use the same Client application to get some data on each client, Then the upload the data each other to firebase(database of main account)

As above requirement, i have a following question as below:

1. I want to use the anonymous user in each client to login firebase and write some data to database, it is feasible?
2. I use the python(Pyrebase), have any reference about creating the anonymous user and access the database?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maiv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Creating anonymous authentication accounts is not supported by Pyrebase it seems, as it's not mentioned in it's [documentation on authentication](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#authentication).